# stop network browsing for clients

Tags: linux, networking

I am using RouterTik OS as my edge router. My clients are connected to one of the LAN cards of this router PC. One of my clients has a MacBook. He can discover all the clients connected to that LAN card. How can i restrict my clients from discovering each other?

Comment: not that much a programming question... try http://superuser.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using an Ethernet switch will mean that one PC can't view traffic directly between two other computers on the same LAN (older Ethernet hubs allowed PCs to capture such traffic).

To prevent a PC from observing broadcast traffic sent by other PCs, you would have to place each PC into a separate broadcast domain. Some routers support VLANs, which is one way to achieve this. Place each PC into a separate VLAN. You can then use router rules to decide which traffic is allowed between PCs. This places a large load on your router and on it's administrator.

You say "RouterTik OS" but if you mean a MikroTik wireless router running RouterOS then the above does not apply. Your MikroTik router may have settings that segregate PCs.

Answer (score 0):

One way ti isolate clients - use separate VLAN each client.
Other way - use filter rules that block broadcasts from clients to clients in switch that support filtering